# Permitir que usuario de Active Directory tenga acceso a una computadora determinada vía "Users and Computers"

Tags: servidor, activedirectory

Ya cree mis usuarios y ya añadí las computadoras a mi dominio. El problema es que cuando me logueo con un usuario creado (por ej: matias.ruiz) me dice lo que dice la imagen. Ya probé agregándolo al grupo Remote Desktop Users y no hay caso. Y la idea es que lo haga desde el Domain Controller, ya que al haber tantas computadoras no me serviría hacerlo desde dentro de cada una.
[image: esto me sale cuando ingreso con la cuenta]